# How to pass object data between action class and jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am having a Java class named Code. It has all the values related to code like `codeId`, `codeDescription` etc with their getters and setters. I am retrieving the data of the Code in one action class successfully (I am using struts 2).

Now I want to get these values in my `display.jsp` page. Clearly I want the data from the object like `codeobj.codeId`, `codeobj.codeDescription` etc to be displayed. How I can do this?

Answer (score 8):

All you need to have is getter and setter methods for the fields in your `Action` class. Struts2 will put that object on the top of `ValueStack` and With the help of `OGNL` you can access the properties from JSP.

Here is the code snippet

```
public class Test Extends ActionSupport{
    public String execute() throws Exception{
     // Action Logic fetching/Init code object
     return SUCCESS;

}

private Code code=null;

public void setCode(Code code){
    this.code=code
}

public Code getCode(){
    return code;
}

}
```

Now Struts2 framework will put the `code` instance on the top of `ValueStack` which is the place where all request processing data is being placed by the framework and being referred by the jsp/Actions using OGNL which is a navigation language to fetch the data.

in your JSP you can access the `code` instance with the following code

```
<s:property value="%{code.codeId}"/>
or
<s:textfield name="abc" value="%{code.codeId}"/>
```

what exactly happening here is that framework has placed your `code` instance with the filled value on the `ValueStack` and with the help of OGNL we are fetching that value.

OGNL will check if there is an instance namd `code` on the top of value stack which will be placed by framework, after it found `code` instance it will check if it has codeId property. On finding the property, `OGNL` will do the data type conversion and will show the value in JSP.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<s:iterate value="codeobj" var="obj"

<s:property value="codeId"/>
<s:property value="codeDescription"/>

</s:iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Pass data from an action to the jsp:
Consider that you want to pass the message from the action to the jsp. First, declare the message as a String variable in the action class. In the Execute method, add the value of the message as showing in the example below:

```
public class TestAction {

String message;
public String execute () {


    System.out.println("Execute method called ");
    message = "SUCCESS Message Ya Maged";


    return "success";
}


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

}
```

---

in the JSP file: 
use the  and the value parameter to get the value of that String message variable that you declared in the action class.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><s:property value="message"/></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How Can I do the opposite jsp to action??

Comment: @AyushPal, The answer is long, how can I share it with you