# How to send values from java class to jsp page ?

Tags: java, android, jsp

I have created two jsp pages in which I am able to get the response of my input. Below are my 2 jsp pages. Also I would like to get a response from android java class to the same Index1.jsp.(For eg: If I am sending one string to Index1.jsp I would to get the response as same string).

Index.jsp

```
<form action="index1.jsp" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="maths" checked="checked" /> Maths
<input type="checkbox" name="physics"  /> Physics
<input type="checkbox" name="chemistry" checked="checked" /> Chem
<input type="submit" value="Select Subject" />
</form>
```

Index1.jsp

```
<%
   Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();

   while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
      out.print("<tr><td>" + paramName + "</td>\n");
      String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);      
      out.println("<td> " + paramValue + "</td></tr>\n");
   }
%>
```

Comment: possible duplicte of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374768/how-to-pass-object-data-between-action-class-and-jsp-page

Comment: Hi shylendra in the above link the output has been achieved through JSTL tags but i would like to have output from index1.jsp file itself..Thanks

Comment: keep the data into request scope varible and get in index1.jsp and  display